# Problem with finding the length of a string using pointers in a function in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, string-length

I got a task from my college which is to find the length of a string using pointers in a function.Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define max 100

int lengthchar(char *array1[])
{
    int a, x = 0;
    for (a = 0; *(array1++) != '\0'; a++)
    {
        x++;
    }
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    char arr1[max];
    int length;

    printf("Enter string\n");
    gets(arr1);

    length = lengthchar(arr1);

    printf("Length=%d", length);

    return 0;
}
```

But when I  give input something bellow:

Enter string: av

Length=9

It shows the wrong length, what's my mistake?

Comment: When passing an array to a function the argument should be `char *array1` or `char array1[]`. BTW, the variable `a` isn't doing anything useful and should be removed.

Comment: FYI: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1694036)

Comment: Listen to your compiler warnings. It will tell you you are using the wrong type when calling the function lengthchar1()

Comment: for loop, I have to use variable a right? @user3386109

Comment: No, you can leave it empty like `for(;*(array1++)!='\0';)`

Comment: Or use a `while` loop: `while (array[x]) x++; return x;`

Comment: In function prototypes, `a[]` is syntactic sugar for `* const a`; a true array of type `int a[1]` can only be passed by a pointer `int (*a)[1]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the way to pass a string pointer as an argument to the function.

Just change `char *array1[]` to char ***array1** or **array1[]**.

Have a look at the implementation below:

```
int lengthchar(char array1[])
{
    int a,x=0;
    for(a=0;*(array1++)!='\0';a++)
    {
        x++;
    }

   return x;
}
```

PS: variable `a` can be removed by using a while loop.

Comment: Or... `x` can be removed and `a` `return`ed.

Comment: @FiddlingBits, Correct!

Comment: Thanks, it helped

Comment: DV-ted for not showing OPs const correctness & correct types

Answer (score 1):

In your function signature, you are telling the compiler that `lenghtchar()` expects a pointer to character strings, or `**char` in other words.

What you really want to do is to change your function from `int lengthchar(char *array1[])` to `int lengthchar(char array1[])` or `int lengthchar(char *array1)`. This is a bit tricky since in C, you can address an array by using the address of its first element (aka, by using pointer to its first item).

[Expert C Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131774298) has a dedicated chapter on this topic.

Now, coming to your `lengthchar()` function, I would do some refactoring to eliminate the variable `a` and use a `while` loop instead. I have also included another alternative implementation that relies on pointer arithmetic (more fun to me :) )

Note also that I used `fgets()` instead of `gets()` which is considered deprecated since it does not do any bounds checking.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define max 100

/* 
 * returns the lenght of the string excluding the terminating 
 * NULL character
 */
int lengthchar(char *array1) {
    int x = 0;
    while (*array1++)
        x++;
    return x-1;
}

int lengthchar1(char *array1){
  char *p;
  for (p = array1; *p; p++)
  ;
  return p - array1 - 1; /* -1 for \0 */
}

int main() {
    char arr1[max];
    int length;

    printf("Enter string\n");
    fgets(arr1, max, stdin);

    length = lengthchar(arr1);

    printf("Length=%d", length);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On declaring or defining a function that shall take an array of type `T` as an argument, use the notation: `T *array` or `T array[]`; `T` may stand for any valid C data type such as `char`, `int`, `float`, `double`, etc...

As for your loop, the variable `a` seems to be redundant because it has no effect on any part of the program. The return value of the function `lengthchar()` is one more than the number of characters inputted.

Also you should avoid the function `gets()` because it is deemed dangerous and has been removed from the C standard; use `fgets()` instead.

Your code should look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define max 100

int lengthchar(char *str)
{
    int len = 0;
    while (*str++)
    {
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}

int main()
{
    char str1[max];

    printf("Enter string:");

    fgets(str1, max, stdin);

    str1[strcspn(str1, "\n")] = 0; // remove new-line character

    int length = lengthchar(str1);

    printf("Length = %d\n", length);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @P__J__ There is no need to overwhelm the OP with new ideas. It is sufficient to point out the error and present the solution.

Comment: @P__J__ Not using `const` is not "not programming correctly" and `int` type is fine instead of `size_t` in toy programs.

Comment: @P__J__, I completely agree with machine_1. Also, the way to write comments is offensive.

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire - I do not think that saying the truth is offensive.  Const correctness and wrong types are one of the most common programming  problems.